# How to fix " 'class' or 'interface' expected in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-intent

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I'm building a basic app in which it can **act as** dialer (it will not be able to make the calls).

So in the **AndroidManifest.xml** I'm getting this error 'class' or 'interface' expected.

Here is the code in the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.falsephone">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <!-- Problem in this line -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" /> <!-- Problem in this line -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.catogory.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.falsephone;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate cache?

Comment: Paste the `MainActivity` file also..

Comment: @Ticherhaz I tried that but was is it's use here?

Comment: @KshitijAgarwal does the problem fixed?

Comment: @Ticherhaz nope